# Performance Comparison of Two Linq Calls

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

Assume that there are two queries running on a memory list;

First query (employing extension methods):

`var temp = listX.Where(q => q.SomeProperty == someValue);`

Second query:

```
var temp = from o in listX
              where o.SomeProperty == someValue
              select o;
```

Is there a difference between two queries in terms of performance; and if there is, why?

Comment: Why didn't you just try yourself?

Comment: I may try it, but isolating is a problem (although I may just examine the assembly output). trying it by just creating a sample may not work if there is slight difference between two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no difference at all. The compiler internally transforms the second version to the first one.

The C# specification (§7.6.12) states:

> The C# language does not specify the execution semantics of query
>   expressions. Rather, query expressions are translated into invocations
>   of methods that adhere to the query expression pattern (§7.16.3).
>   Specifically, query expressions are translated into invocations of
>   methods named `Where`, `Select`, `SelectMany`, `Join`, `GroupJoin`, `OrderBy`,
>   `OrderByDescending`, `ThenBy`, `ThenByDescending`, `GroupBy`, and `Cast`.These
>   methods are expected to have particular signatures and result types,
>   as described in §7.16.3. These methods can be instance methods of the
>   object being queried or extension methods that are external to the
>   object, and they implement the actual execution of the query.
>
> The translation from query expressions to method invocations is a
>   syntactic mapping that occurs before any type binding or overload
>   resolution has been performed. The translation is guaranteed to be
>   syntactically correct, but it is not guaranteed to produce
>   semantically correct C# code. Following translation of query
>   expressions, the resulting method invocations are processed as regular
>   method invocations, and this may in turn uncover errors, for example
>   if the methods do not exist, if arguments have wrong types, or if the
>   methods are generic and type inference fails.

Comment: +1, The second option will be compiled to the first one, which is easy to see when using LINQPad.

Comment: @Jon so can I assume that using extension method simply adds no overhead at all?

Comment: @daryal: The second form is "syntactic sugar". It only exists in source code. Does the excerpt not answer your other question? ("These methods can be...").

Answer (score 4):

There aren't differences. It will produce the same result in the same time. It's basically the same code with different syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Short question, short answer:

There is no difference. Both are the same, just written in different syntax.

See also the MSDN documentation for [Query Syntax and Method Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx).